Does Vercel's maxDuration override the timeout of a http socket connection inside a server action?
I have a nextJs app that has a call to an email notifications client that uses a http socket connection to receive a trigger. This is initiated inside a server action that itself is called in response to a few server actions as part of a logic process flow.
In order to increase the maxDuration of the call I had to set the maxDuration property at the SSR page level as mentioned here (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#maxduration)

If using Server Actions, set the maxDuration at the page level to change the default timeout of all Server Actions used on the page.

But the page level maxDuration has started resetting the timeout causing the TLS handshake to completely fail, and that is the only connection I can make. Can someone guide on if this assumption is true? I failed to find anything on this topic.
